# What is a word that means "trouble with opposites"? (read for detail)

Tags: single-word-requests

As in, the person has trouble telling **right** or **left**, **up** or **down**, **positive** or **negative**, **west**/**east**

The word in my head is pronounced "---lysic".

Comment: The person has difficulty telling the difference between  *up* and  *down*? They don't understand what is *up* when they read the word or in real life? Like some people who confuse their left with their right.

Comment: A person who has trouble telling the difference between antonyms (opposites) is *not* dyslexic. You have misunderstood what *dyslexia* means.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean ***[dyslexic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dyslexic):***

[Dyslexia](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dyslexia):

> - any of various reading disorders associated with impairment of the ability to interpret spatial relationships or to integrate auditory and visual information.

(dictionary.reference.com)

Comment: Of course, dyslexia is essentially a *reading* disorder, and does not imply difficulties with telling right from left or having spacial orientation problems not associated with reading.